# docker: Error response from daemon when using -it /bin/bash

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to interactively start my image id by using the following command .

`docker run -it 39d2842d5caa /bin/bash`

However this fails giving me the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

But when i start using the following command it works.

`docker run -it 39d2842d5caa sh`

My OS: is Mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is reported when the binary that the container is told to execute (in this case `/bin/bash`) is not available.

It sounds like this is an image based off Alpine Linux which doesn't have bash in it by default, only `sh`.

Doing a `docker inspect 39d2842d5caa` should give you more information, specifically the `ContainerConfig.Cmd` part.